# How to make this RL code get GPU support?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, reinforcement-learning

https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/dqn.py#L52

```
def replay(self, batch_size):
    minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
    for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
        target = reward
        if not done:
            target = (reward + self.gamma *
                      np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
        target_f = self.model.predict(state)
        target_f[0][action] = target
        self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

This code seems can't get help from GPU since it trains data once per action.

```
self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

How to change this code to train in parallel, then get help from GPU?

Comment: Please install GPU version of Tensorflow, by the following: `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. And then call the models, layers like: `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential` and so on...

Comment: I tested this code on Google colab directly, it can choose GPU or TPU. However, I can't see improvement compared to supervised training, ex: MNIST. In MNIST, it is easy to see 10x - 20x speed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Reinforcement Learning (RL) there is often a lot of CPU computation required for each sample step (of course dependent on environment, some environments can use GPU too). The RL-model has a hard time understanding the rewards and what action caused that specific reward, since a good reward could be dependent on a way earlier action. Therefore we want a simple model-architectures (shallow and fewer weights) while doing RL, else the training time will be way to slow. Hence your systems bottle neck is likely gathering samples rather than training the data. 
Also Note that not all Tensorflow-architectures scale equally well with GPU. Deep models with high numbers of weights like most Images cases scales super well (like CNN and MLP network with MNIST), while time-dependent RNN has less speedup potential (see [this stackexchange question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/can-lstm-nets-be-speed-up-by-gpu)). So set your expectation accordingly when using GPU.

Through my RL experience, I have figured some possible speedups I could share, and would love to see more suggestions!

1. Single sample step, can be speed up by creating multiple environment run in parallel, equal to the number of CPU cores (there are packages for parallel processing in python you can use fore this). This can potential speed up sampling data proportional to the number of CPU cores.
2. Between sampling you have to do model predictions for next action. Instead of calling model.predict at each step, you can call a single model.predict for all your parallel states (using a batch_size equal to the number of parallel environments). This will speed up prediction time, as there is more optimization options.
3. The change from updating model weights to prediction is surprisingly slow. Hopefully this will be speed up in the future? But while the change is as slow as today, you can speed up training by holding the model constant and do lots of sample and prediction (example a whole episode, or multiple steps within an episode), then train the model on all the newly gathered data afterwards. In my case this resulted in periodically high GPU utilization.
4. Since sampling is most likely the bottle neck, you can make a historical repo of state, action, rewards. Than at training you can sample randomly data from this repo and train it together with the newly gathered data. This is known as "Experience Replay" in RL.
5. Maybe the most fun, and highest potential for improvements is by using more advance RL-learning architectures. Example changing the loss function (check out [PPO](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) for example), using and tuning the "generalized advantage estimation" calculated by the rewards. Or changing the model by for example including time dependencies with RNN, [VAC](http://kvfrans.com/variational-autoencoders-explained/) or combining them all like [here](https://worldmodels.github.io).

Hopefully this help you speed up the training time, and maybe get more utilization of your GPU.

Comment: Here is an example on how to train and predict in different threads, and a description of the train/pred switch/initiation slowdown (maybe due to model.build?) and how to overcome this tensorflow problem [Self-driving cars with Carla and Python p.4 (33:00-34:11)](https://youtu.be/hWLurYddo88?t=1980) together with [Self-driving cars with Carla and Python p.5 (04:11-05:35)](https://youtu.be/MynOPIJi4VY?t=251)